# JQuery Mobile, Adding Class to dynamic id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've run into a little problem with adding a class to dynamically added content.

Here is the whole function:

```
$("#mainschulden").click(function(){
if(instanse){
    instanse = false;
    $("#maincontent").empty();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:  "schuldenapp.php",
        data:{
            'function': 'mainschulden',
            'sessionid': sessionid,
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            instanse = true;
            for (i = 0, len = data.schuldenliste.length; i < len; i++){
                var betrag = data.schuldenliste[i]['betrag'];
                var idbetrag = data.schuldenliste[i]['idschuld'];
                var vorname = data.schuldenliste[i]['lendervorname'];
                var nachname = data.schuldenliste[i]['lendernachname'];
                var schuldelement = "<div data-role=\"collapsible\" id=\"" + idbetrag + "\"><h3>" + vorname + " " + nachname + ": CHF " + betrag +"</h3><div data-role=\"controlgroup\" data-mini=\"true\" data-type=\"horizontal\"><input data-role=\"button\" type=\"button\" value=\"accept\" data-icon=\"check\" name=\"" + idbetrag + "\"><input data-role=\"button\" type=\"button\" value=\"decline\" data-icon=\"delete\" name=\""+idbetrag+"\"><input data-role=\"button\" type=\"button\" value=\"payed\" data-icon=\"star\" name=\""+idbetrag+"\"></div></div>";
                $("#maincontent").append(schuldelement);
                $("#" + idbetrag).addClass("burrower_accept");
            }
            $("#maincontent").enhanceWithin();
        },
    });
}
```

});

I'm adding a number of elements to the content div, which works, but if i want to add the class to the collapsible div's id, it will just be ignored.

The result in the browser looks like that:

```
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true" data-type="horizontal" class="ui-controlgroup ui-controlgroup-horizontal ui-corner-all ui-mini"><div class="ui-controlgroup-controls "><div class="ui-btn ui-input-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-icon-check ui-btn-icon-left ui-first-child">accept<input data-role="button" type="button" value="accept" data-icon="check" name="5634cebf18ec82.75828423"></div><div class="ui-btn ui-input-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-left">decline<input data-role="button" type="button" value="decline" data-icon="delete" name="5634cebf18ec82.75828423"></div><div class="ui-btn ui-input-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-icon-star ui-btn-icon-left ui-last-child">payed<input data-role="button" type="button" value="payed" data-icon="star" name="5634cebf18ec82.75828423"></div></div></div>
```

as we can see, the class is not present in the HTML, also the console doesn't throw an error message.

May you please suggest me where I do wrong?

Comment: The result you have provided is of a child div of div with id idbetrag. Verify whether the class has been added in the parent div, that has id idbetrag.

Answer (score 0):

To add class to a dynamic id, do this

```
 $('#'+ idbetrag+'').addClass('burrower_accept');
```

Instead of

```
 $("#" + idbetrag).addClass("burrower_accept");
```

Comment: unfortunatly your suggestion did not change the behaviour of the script, class still missing at runtime